# Visual Studio 2012 Installation Issues

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I just finished installing visual studio 2012 from an .iso image and when it finished installing i got these 2 errors:

1. > Microsoft Web Deploy 3.0
   >
   > A required certificate is not within its
   >   validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the
   >   timestamp in the signed file.
2. > Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64) Package failed

Should i be worried? I made sure i uninstalled 2010 before i installed 2012 and i did a registry cleanup not sure if that helped or made it worse.

Comment: You can install that separately anyway.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178739.aspx

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't think so !! 
by the way , you  can solve this issues by updates from microsoft and also these links might help : 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872457
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178739.aspx